# MVC4 linq query to object doesn't come out as the correct object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, iqueryable

Error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery (snip) ...looking for type 'Advocate'

Controller method looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AdvocateEdit(int id)
{
    var advocate = from a in db.Query<Advocate>().Include(a => a.AdvocateId)
                   where (a.AdvocateId == id)
                   select a;

    return View(advocate);
}
```

The view is indeed typed to the Advocate @model and after stepping through, I'm pretty sure the problem is this query. It needs to be of type Advocate when it returns.

```
db.Query is an IQueryable<T> method in my DbContext that returns Set<T>().
```

Let me know if more info is needed.  Thanks people

ADDED ----

DbContext.cs

```
public interface IAcmeDb : IDisposable
{
    IQueryable<T> Query<T>() where T : class;
}

public class AcmeDb : DbContext, IAcmeDb
{
    public AcmeDb() : base("name=AcmeDB") {}
    public DbSet<Advocate> Advocates { get; set; }

    IQueryable<T> IAcmeDb.Query<T>()
    {
         return Set<T>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your view requires a single `Advocate` and there is always only one entity for a given id then you want:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AdvocateEdit(int id)
{
   try
   {
       Advocate advocate = db.Query<Advocate>().Single(a => a.AdvocateId == id);
       return View(advocate);
   }
   catch(InvalidOperationException ex)
   {
      //handle the case where no entity matches the supplied id (return status code 404?), or
      //there are no Advocates at all (redirect to a create page?), or
      //more than one entity matches (return status code 500)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to pass an Advocate element to the view, not the query itself. Try this:

```
return View(advocate.First());
```

The advocate object in your code is of type IQueryable, if your view expects an Advocate object, just get the first element of the query with First() or FirstOrDefault().

Comment: break point on the return has 'advocate' as type System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<Advocate>.  advocate.First() throws an invalid operation {"A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'Acme.Web.Models.Advocate' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'AdvocateId'."}

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with .Include(a => a.AdvocateId)?, I don't think you need that.

Comment: was just trying to grab a specific record...been doing low level windows services programming for a while so my linq is pretty rusty.

Answer (score 2):

There is at least one notable problem. LINQ tends to use deferred execution. No where in your code do I see you forcing the query to execute. Unless somewhere in `View(advocate)` you enumerate the `IEnumberable<T>` produced by the query then you will not be dealing with objects of type `Advocate`.

I would recommend adding a `ToList()` or `ToArray()` call to the end of your query, this will ensure that it actually gets executed. If that doesn't work I would break the query apart and make sure `db.Query<Advocate>()` is returning what you'd expect.

```
   List<Advocate> = db.Query<Advocate>().Include(a => a.AdvocateId)
                    .Where(a.AdvocateId == id)
                    .Select(a => a).ToList();
```

I've converted your query to method syntax since it's what's familiar to me. The above example will likely solve your problems. I think to keep query syntax you should just put the whole left hand side in parents then tack on the `ToList()` call however I'm not certain what the correct syntax is.

EDIT: Based on other comments the problem was not the deferred execution but rather the attempt to pass a collection to a method looking for a single instance. Going with the same code above, you just need to change the `ToList()` to `FirstOrDefault()` and your code will work;

```
List<Advocate> = db.Query<Advocate>().Include(a => a.AdvocateId)
                        .Where(a.AdvocateId == id)
                        .Select(a => a).FirstOrDefault();
```

Note: the default value for reference types is `null` this could of course cause you problems if you don't have the proper checks in place for nullity.

Comment: initially I was just using db.Advocates.Find(id) and that was working just fine but then I had to go and get fancy and set up a db interface so I could do unit testing against a fake db.  should probably just switch everything back so I can keep moving forward

Comment: But your code would still be a collection of Advocate rather than an Advocate so it wouldn't fix the error. Also, even if it the view did take a collection, there is usually no need to materialise the query in the controller. If the view needs the entities it will enumerate the query. If it doesn't need them, then executing the query in the controller is wasteful. And maybe the view will apply a further filter or something, in which case your approach will have fetched more entities than necessary,

Comment: @MikeGoodwin good point. I overlooked the fact that his view was looking for a singleton.